# How do I implement dynamically sized data structures in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, data-structures, data-science

I am trying to implement a dynamically sized data structure in MATLAB.

I have a 2D plane with nodes. For each node I need to save the coordinates and the coordinates of the nodes around it, within a distance of e.g. 100.
Imagine a circle with a radius of 100 around each node. I want to store all nodes within this circle for every node.

For example:

```
-----------------------------------------------
|                                             |
|   x                                         |
|                                  x          |
|                                             |
|         x                                   |
|                               x             |
|                    x                        |
|                                             |
|        x                                    |
-----------------------------------------------
```

I tried to implement this as shown below. I create a `NodeList` which contains a `NodeStruct` for every node. Every `NodeStruct` contains the coordinates of its corresponding node, as well as an array of the nodes around it. The problem with the implementation which I had in mind is, that the variable `NodeStruct.NextNode` changes its size for every Node.

I have an idea on how to find all the nodes, my problem is the datastructure to store all the necessary information.

```
NodeList = [];
NodeStruct.Coords = [];
NodeStruct.NextNode = [];
```

Comment: Why do you have to change the structure of `NodeStruct`? `NodeStruct.Coords` will keep the coordinates of the node itself and `NodeStruct.NextNode` would be an n*2 matrix keeping all surrounding nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a struct array that you index as follows:

```
NodeStruct(3).Coords = [x,y];
NodeStruct(3).NextNode = [1,2,6,10];
```

However, it is likely that this is better solved with an adjacency matrix. That is an NxN matrix, with N the number of nodes, and where `adj(i,j)` is true if nodes `i` and `j` are within the given distance of each other. In this case, the adjacency matrix is symmetric, but it doesn't need to be if you list, for example, the 10 nearest nodes for each node. That case can also be handled with the adjacency matrix.

Given an Nx2 matrix with coordinates `coord`, where each row is the coordinates for one node, you can write:

```
dist = sqrt(sum((reshape(coord,[],1,2) - reshape(coord,1,[],2)).^2, 3));
adj = dist < 100; % or whatever your threshold is
```